# Creating and reading z values (coordinates) with pyshp?

Tags: coordinates, pyshp, z-value

I am trying to parse an input shapefile which consists of multiple polygons and want to create a new shapefile from this with added z values. Each polygon of the input shapefile is defined by multiple points, whereas each of these is defined by an x and y coordinate.

I am creating a new shapefile with x, y (simply copied from input shapefile) and z coordinates like so:

```
s = shapefile.Writer()
s.autoBalance = 1
s.shapeType = 15 // PolygonZ
pointlist = [[12345.123, 45678.123, 10.0], [23456.123, 34567.123, 10.0]]
s.poly(shapeType=s.shapeType, parts=[pointlist])
s.save("test.shp")
```

But now when I want to read this created shapefile I can't see the defined z values:

```
s = shapefile.Reader("test.shp")
print(s.shapes()[0].points) // [[12345.123, 45678.123]]
```

What am I missing that the z values aren't included? I have also tried to define the polygon with at least 4 points (where the last point is identical to the first one) - exactly like the docs are stating to do this, but this didn't help either.

When I am trying to read the z value of the first point of a polygon with QGIS I can easily see my specified values:

```
z(start_point($geometry)) // 10
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you examine [GeospatialPython.com: Working with Elevation Values in Shapefiles](http://geospatialpython.com/2011_03_01_archive.html) (the blog of Joel Lawhead, creator of the Pyshp module)

> When you read 3D shapefiles the elevation values will be stored separately....And know that the z values are stored in the "z" property of each shape instead of being integrated with the x,y value lists.

From the supplied example:

```
r = shapefile.Reader("MyPolyZ")
first = r.shapes()[0]
dir(first)
['__doc__', '__geo_interface__', '__init__', '__module__', 'bbox', 'parts', 'points', 'shapeType', 'z']
first.points
[(-89.0, 33.0), (-90.0, 31.0), (-91.0, 30.0), (-89.0, 33.0)]
first.z
[12.0, 11.0, 12.0, 12.0]
```