# PointZ elevation issue PYSHP

Tags: python, gdal, pyshp

I have created a shapefile with approximately 300 feature of shapeType POINTZ. I can fill my attributs and define point.
Here is my function that i call for each feature:

```
def upd_shp(fn, geo, attr):
    r = shapefile.Reader(fn)
    w = shapefile.Writer(r.shapeType)
    w.fields = list(r.fields)
    w.records.extend(r.records())
    w._shapes.extend(r.shapes())
    x = geo[1]
    y = geo[0]
    z = geo[2]
    w.point(x, y, z)
    w.record(*attr)
    w.save(fn)
```

Then when i do `ogrinfo -al myshp.shp` i can see `POINT (8.833808735269852 42.540690712189829)` but there is not  'z' value. 
When i do `ogrinfo -al example.shp` which it's a shapefile made by my company i can see `POINT (8.75044460305986 42.567946874150579 37.384099928078562)`.

I know my 'z' is in the shapefile but i don't understand why i can't see it with ogrinfo.

I searched and I found [Creating and reading z values (coordinates) with pyshp?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/231180) but it did not help me much.

I would like to know if i'm missing something?

Comment: Are you sure that you are creating the shapefile with a type of POINTZ (does ogrinfo report that)? You may need to include some of the code for that.

Comment: Yes i'm sure, this is the code for the shapefile creation 
`def first_shp(fn):
 ff = os.path.isfile(fn)
 if ff is False:
  ww = shapefile.Writer(shapeType=11)
  for x in attr_list_full:
   ww.field(x)
  ww.save(fn)`

and to be sure it's POINTZ :
`>>> import shapefile
>>> r = shapefile.Reader('/myshp/attr_def.shp')
>>> r.shapeType
11`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the `shapeType` when creating the point.

```
w.point(x,y,z, shapeType=shapefile.POINTZ)
```

Looking at the [source](https://github.com/GeospatialPython/pyshp/blob/master/shapefile.py#L1315), the `shapeType` parameter of `point` defaults to `POINT`:

```
def point(self, x, y, z=0, m=NODATA, shapeType=POINT):
    """Creates a point shape."""
    pointShape = Shape(shapeType)
    ...
```

The [docs](https://github.com/GeospatialPython/pyshp#adding-geometry) does also states that, although it's not exactly clear as it could be.

> An optional z (elevation) and m (measure) value can be set if the shapeType is PointZ or PointM.